# Showing encrypted password in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, password-encryption

In my application, I want to show my users their passwords. But, I encrypt the password when then sign up. So, when I am displaying their password, it is displayed in that encrypted format, but I want to show them the real(decrypted) passwords. I used this to encrypt the password while registering(sign up) :

```
AuthComponent::password($password)
```

where, `$password` is the password I am registering.

What to do here ? What should I do ? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your design is flawed. You should **never** ever display the password in plaintext, not on signup, not after hashing, never. And it's not possible either - as explained in numerous posts across the internet hashing is one-way.

Comment: Hmm, got it. Looks like I have to go another way. By the way, thanks :) @mark